# How to add a button to @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

Here I am a beginner in MVC but I would like to add a button to my `@Html.ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "Index",new { @class = "btn btn-info", id = m.pro_id })
```

I am using bootstrap css , but it looks like it doesn't apply.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following [`Html.ActionLink()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method, that contains a route parameters and next is the HTML attributes for the button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "Index",  
        routeValues: new { id = m.pro_id }, 
        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-info" })
```